MacBook Air battery slows everything down after visiting service for diagnostics
I have a 2018 MacBook Air that recently stopped working unless it was plugged in, even though the battery had been newly replaced.
Yesterday, I took it to a service center for diagnostics, and they informed me that the battery needs to be replaced again.
However, after getting it back, my MacBook is now running extremely slowly. It struggles to open a browser or any file larger than an image. Additionally, I noticed that the battery cycle count has been reset.
I've reset SMC and NVRAM - no effect. Unfortunately I can not install CoconutBattery suggested elsewhere, because my browser doesn't open now...
Has anyone experienced similar issues or have any suggestions on what might be causing this and how to fix it? Could the battery have been replaced during diagnostics?
Battery Information:

  Charge Information:
  The battery’s charge is below the warning level:  No
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   0
  Health Information:
  Cycle Count:  0

System Power Settings:

  AC Power:
  System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 0
  Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes):   10
  Display Sleep Timer (Minutes):    0
  Wake on AC Change:    No
  Wake on Clamshell Open:   Yes
  Wake on LAN:  Yes
  Current Power Source: Yes
  Display Sleep Uses Dim:   Yes
  Hibernate Mode:   3
  LowPowerMode: 0
  PrioritizeNetworkReachabilityOverSleep:   0

Hardware Configuration:

  UPS Installed:    No

AC Charger Information:

  Connected:    Yes

Power Events:

Next Scheduled Events:

  appPID:   372
  Type: Wake
  Scheduled By: com.apple.alarm.user-visible-com.apple.CalendarNotification.EKTravelEngine.periodicRefreshTimer
  Time: 25.06.2024, 03:01
  UserVisible:  0

  appPID:   85
  Type: Wake
  Scheduled By: com.apple.alarm.user-visible-com.apple.acmd.alarm
  Time: 25.06.2024, 18:57
  UserVisible:  0

How can I check if my battery has been replaced during diagnostics?

Welcome to Ask Different.  Who did the first repair? Apple or Apple Authorized repair or third party or DIY? Was the part direct from Apple? Who is doing the second service? You have left a lot of details out and we can speculate or get a better picture if you can edit a few key parts to this story in the question.

both times i went to a 'Authorized' service, but in different countries.

Well, you could call Apple direct and ask to have them interpret the notes each authorized center saved to your case. I would have expected an authorized center to do a much more professional job explaining what they found and depending on how long a time elapsed between visits, you should get a complimentary repair if you paid for the first and it didn’t last even 90 days. Definitely reach out to Apple  to get the authorizer’s view of these service events.

I would expect the battery cycle count to be reset after a new battery is installed. Ultimately, if the repair made things worse, then that's a problem for the shop.

Zero FCC and zero cycles sounds like the controller has failed or is grey market. I would get a recommendation direct from Apple with remote battery service diagnostics without knowing a lot of details about who is sourcing the parts and who is opening this Mac to repair it.
If you’re putting good batteries in that are known good, it’s not the battery that’s failing. But uncertain quality refurbished batteries mean it could just need one solid battery to work. It’s very hard for us to guess which.
You’ll need a repair shop that has access to Apple diagnostics and a known good battery to test this properly.

both times i went to 'Authorized' service, but in different countries. i have no idea which battery they've installed, unfortunately, was expecting them to do the authorised thing

remote battery service diagnostics is running for several hours already, i am not sure if it actually is doing something or not

That’s a very fair expectation. I would call Apple to ask them to review the notes from both centers and advise. They can run a remote diagnostic and check the work of the most recent service. You may have to mail it in if the machine is failing so much that it can not complete the diagnostic. Keep your receipts to get reimbursed if needed and indicated.
